# Is it possible to add video to alarm app in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to add video to my alarm app which I have created so that instead of music, video should be played. Is it possible to add video to alarm? I have not found that in alarm class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short - No. Alarms not configurable and always must be recognizable by a user